# Re-scaling output values of a topic

Tags: ros, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys! I'm working on a teleop project with a Spacenav joystick for a UR5e robot arm. I've remapped the topic to which the spacenav_node published originally to `/twist_controller/command` but the values which the joystick sends are too big for the robot arm to safely use and so the safety is triggered. How do I re-scale the values to more optimal ones? The maximum values which the joystick publishes are ~0.9. How do I scale that range down to -0.04 and 0.04?

I'm thinking of making a separate package which launches in parallel to the spacenav one and which takes the output values and divides them by a constant. Is this a viable solution or is there a simpler method to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387180/re-scaling-output-values-of-a-topic/) by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarioSpeckert](https://answers.ros.org/users/1561/mariospeckert/) on 2021-09-23**:
Hi, I'm not an expert, so this is not an answer, but your solution would also be my approach to solve this. A simple subscriber who publishes the scaled date to a new topic. Another approach could be to implement a scaling factor in the spacenav node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Besides writing a custom node, I can come up with two options:

1. treat your spacenav as a joystick, and use something like [teleop_tools/joy_teleop](http://wiki.ros.org/joy_teleop). That node supports scaling and a few other options which seem to do what you describe
2. keep using raw values from your spacenav, but scale them using [topic_tools/transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform). That node subscribes to a topic, runs it through a Python expression and then publishes the result to (preferably) a new topic. A previous Q&A about `transform` is #q261935, which shows how to format complex expressions

I've used both in the past.

Option 1 will probably be the easiest to implement. Option 2 is the most flexible, as it's *almost* a custom node, but then as an argument to the `topic_tools/transform` node.

In any case: try to avoid writing code yourself as much as possible.

And something to realise: *any* additional nodes (or really: publishers and subscribers) you place between your input device and the final consumer of your `Twist`s is going to add delay and jitter. That may not be a problem in your case, but it is something to keep in mind when working with such a system.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2